# Must a closed totally path-disconnected subset of the sphere have connected complement?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

This question (which is more a curiosity than a research problem) originates from these two:

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720254/is-there-a-nonempty-open-bounded-subset-of-plane-whose-boundary-contains-no-1-di
2. [complement of a totally disconnected closed set in the plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55718/complement-of-a-totally-disconnected-closed-set-in-the-plane)

The first question basically asks: does there exist a non-dense, open subset of $S^2$ whose boundary contains no image of injective paths? I think that this reduces to asking for an open, non-dense set whose boundary is totally path-disconnected.

If we remove the word "path", then the answer is given in question 2. Is the answer easy/known/unknown including the word "path"?

Comment: What do _totally path connected_ and _totally path disconnected_ mean? Totally disconnected according to Engelking's General topology means for each $x$ the quasi-component (= intersection of all clopen sets containing $x$) is $\{x\}$. Please include definitions or a reference.

Comment: I don't know it there is standard terminology. I would say that A is totally path disconnected if every continuous function $[0,1]\to A$ is constant.

Comment: Sorry I realized that I stated badly question 1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A circular version of the [pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) (where you construct it out of "circular chains" whose ends connect up to each other) is a counterexample.  It is connected and totally path-disconnected, and its complement has two components.  This example seems to be due to Bing (Example 2 of [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102613150)).

Comment: I am so upset ... I knew the answer but my internet connection broke :) So anyway, just give a link to a recent paper about the pseudo-circle (as defined in continuum theory), and with more current references see [`arXiv`](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1139) or [`Proc.AMS`](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-03/S0002-9939-08-09605-6/)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey you say that the pseudo arc is totally path-disconnected.  Is it true that constant functions form $[0,1]$ to the pseudo-arc are constant? It follows form the fact that it is ereditary indecomposable, and that the continuous image is a  decomposable continuum?

Comment: @user126154: That's correct.